# Как отправлять заявки с сайта напрямую пользователю в Telegram?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Отправку через бота реализовал, можно ли отправлять напрямую пользователю и как это реализовать? 
Вот код отправки через бота:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$token = "...";
$chat_id = "-327343925";
$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone
);
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
?>
```

Comment: Можно отправлять, если они начинали диалог с ботом. Иначе просто так сообщение через бота пользователю не отправить.

Comment: что значит *отправлять напрямую пользователю*?

Comment: не через бота а сразу с сайта пользователю